# Can a LsitFragment work with ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

**EDIT:** Attached is my code for the custom adapter:

```
public class ListAdapterFeed  extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    Context mContext;

    public ListAdapterFeed(Context context, List<String> feedList){
        super(context, R.layout.fragment_news_feed, feedList);

        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View contentView , ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = contentView;
        if (row == null){
            row = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_feed, null);
        }
        //  update your inner views value here
        return row;
    }
}
```

And the Exception I get in runtime now:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot
>   be cast to android.app.Activity

I'm trying to work with a ListFragment, and a ListView... 
But I get a runtime error telling me that:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2627)
            at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1259)
            at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1171)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:698)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:494)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:666)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2586)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2191)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1354)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1537)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1251)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6379)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2627)
            at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1259)
            at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1171)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:698)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:494)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:666)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2586)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2191)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1354)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1537)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1251)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6379)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't want to work with a TextView, because I want to add a listener and I would like to add items to the view along the way.

Any ideas?

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: You need to create a custom Adapter

Comment: Added the custom adapter the the exception I get....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_news_feed, rssFeed));
```

As the crash log shows the `ArrayAdapter` expects the list item to have at least one `TextView` to update the values in rssFeed.

You need to create a simple custom Adapter and just Override the getView() like this

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View contentView , ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = contentView;
    if (row == null){
        row = mContext.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_feed, null);
    }
    //  update your inner views value here
    return row;
}
```

Now you can set the custom `Adapter` to the `ListFragment`

```
setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(context));
```

Comment: OK, Fixed by using LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);